# Rolling a fair die experiment

Tags: probability, dice

A fair die is rolled. The events $E_1, \dots, E_5$ are defined as follows:

$E_1$: an even number is obtained;

$E_2$: an odd number is obtained;

$E_3$: a score of less than 2 is obtained; *note: is score a key word hinting tossing the die twice?*

$E_4$: a 3 is obtained;

$E_5$: a score of more than 3 is obtained;

Find: $P(E_1 \cap E_3)$, and also $P(E_3 \cap E_5)$

The Book's solutions (which I do not understand) is:

$P(E_1 \cap E_3)=0$ likelihood,

$P(E_3 \cap E_5)= 0$ likelihood.

How come? And thanks.

Comment: For $P(E_1\cap E_3)$...which outcomes are included in $E_1$?  Which are included in $E_3$?  Do these events have any outcomes in common?

Comment: As for "*is score a key word hinting tossing the die twice*?"  No.  Nothing suggests the die is rolled twice.  To the contrary, the sentence "*A fair die is rolled*" with no further clarification implies that we can safely assume that it is meant that it is rolled once (*as well as we can assume that it is a standard fair six-sided die with the usual numbers appearing on the faces*).

Comment: I thank you all much !

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: Meant to say that E3 is 1/6, with roll 1, and E5 is 3/6 with rolls 4,5 and 6. So therefore they do not have anything in common.

Comment: If two events are *mutually exclusive*, meaning they cannot occur at the same time, then the probability that they both occur is $0$.